# Safari Remote Debugging picking up device but not showing any elements

Tags: ios, macos, safari, mobile-safari, safari-web-inspector

I can't get the remote inspector to actually display any elements, its finding my device fine, the website on my phone will highlight when hovering over it in the develop menu, but when clicking through its just blank.

Both devices are on the latest OS. The issue is with my phone and not the Mac as I have tried another device and it worked as expected.

any ideas would be appreciated

[image: develop menu]

[image: inspector]

Answer (score 1):

It can also help to Clear the Trusted Computers under the Developer Preferences on your iOS Device and Re-Pair it with the Mac you'd like to remote debug with.

(I previously tried a MacOS Update, some technical previews for Safari etc. and the method above was the way to save the issue).

Answer (score 0):

Download this to get the most up-to-date version of whatever and it works 
https://developer.apple.com/safari/technology-preview/

Comment: Hi. Is there an alternative to this if I'm having the same issue but cannot download the new up to date version of that software due to incompatibility with my OS?

Comment: lol I literally am experiencing this literal same problem rn.. what are the chances.. I'm following this thread/solution hoping OP or commenter reply https://stackoverflow.com/questions/59783891/safari-technology-preview-cannot-be-installed-on-disk/59803009#59803009