# Safari Technology Preview cannot be installed on disk

Tags: xcode, macos, safari, macos-mojave

I have an iMac with macOS Mojave v10.14.5, and I downloaded Safari Technology Preview 98 but when I try to install it it says that:

> Safari Technology Preview can't be installed on this disk. This volume does not meet the requirements for this update.

I have 465GB free space on my disk so I highly doubt that this would be case. It would be good if there were any more errors, warnings I could go after, but thats all.. Any ideas on how to solve this? My ultimate goal would be to debug a website in more depth.

Comment: any solutions ?

Comment: Yes, I found an answer which will most likely be good to anyone, in this post: https://apple.stackexchange.com/a/341222/359366
So basically, the problem is that the newest version is only compatible with the newest OS version, which I cannot install anymore since my iMac is a 2013 one. The solution is to download an official previous copy, which you can do by checking a previous version of the website with archive.rog, fetch the download link from there, because the files are still on Apple's server's.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I found an answer which will most likely be good to anyone, in this post: [Stack overflow post](https://apple.stackexchange.com/a/341222/359366)

So basically, the problem is that the newest version is only compatible with the newest OS version, which I cannot install anymore since my iMac is a 2013 one. The solution is to download an official previous version, which you can only do by checking a previous version on the download site with archive.rog, fetch the download link from there, because the files are still on Apple's server's and download it.

As of the day it happend - 2020.01.18 - I downloaded the version from 2019.06 something, and it works perfectly.

Comment: hey @zh4siest I'm struggling to find this archive page with the instructions you've provided.. could you reply with an example link please? I'm trying to install an older version off safari technology preview

Comment: Just go to this page: https://web.archive.org/web/*/https://developer.apple.com/safari/download/ and then go back in the calendar around the time - or a bit earlier - when that version was released

Comment: The last version for Mojave listed on [archive.org](https://web.archive.org/web/20200604140813/https://developer.apple.com/safari/download/) was 107 from May 28th, 2020, and the direct link to that version is: https://secure-appldnld.apple.com/STP/001-09573-20200527-5319cd41-1eb4-412a-817a-bf376957b539/SafariTechnologyPreview.dmg

Comment: But note that the current version of normal Safari available for Mojave is a lot newer, at 14.0.3 at present (compared to 13.2 at the link I posted above). Also, once you install the Technology Preview, Software Update will ask to install the latest version of normal Safari, even if it's already on your system. Proceeding with this update changes nothing, except making the update notification disappear.